# При запуске команды repaint(), на месте маленькой панели отрисовывается весь фрейм

Tags: swing

Я прописываю классом checkbox. А в классе main, который задаёт большой фрейм, на который всё и крепится, на эту область стоит Listener. И вот, он ловит нажатие кнопки в ту область, всё идёт как нужно, я дебажил, на ней рисуется крестик drawline'ами и он виден (cм. изображение ниже). А вот при повторном нажатии на эту область он должен исчезать засчёт выполнения нижеприведённого метода, который просто пересоздаёт объект класса checkbox. Но после выполнения

```
public void FirstToDeactive(){

        this.remove(first);

        first = new oneCheckBox();
        first.setBounds(20,32, 481, 481);

        add(first);
        first.repaint();
    }
```

происходит отрисовка всего фрейма на месте маленького чекбокса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема, как оказалось, в том, что я крестик рисую на нём не внутри самого класса, а из Main фрейма. Исправив это, соблюдая основные принципы ООП всё заработало